# changing the value for label

Tags: swift, uilabel, viewcontroller

I've create a login page with functions well but after logging in I want the user to be able to confirm his/her data every time they use the login

The problem is I can Get the email address into another UIViewController but I cant change the text of my label which shows the email and it says unwrapping nil ....

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class userIdConfirmationViewController : UIViewController {



    var emailHolder = String()


    @IBOutlet var emailConfirmation: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var nameConfirmation: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var usernameConfirmation: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         //here is the Error              
         emailConfirmation.text = emailHolder
    }

    @IBAction func ConfirmationButton(sender: UIButton) {
        let email = emailConfirmation.text
        let name = nameConfirmation.text
        let username = usernameConfirmation.text

        print (" email : \(email)       name : \(name)      username : \(username)" )



    }

}
```

Comment: I have just tried your code and it runs fine. So the problem may be in some other part of your project.

Comment: `it says unwrapping nil` There's your issue. It's not related to anything else. Your label is just not properly connected in Interface Builder. Connect it again.

Comment: Thanks @Eric D yeah I got it , The problem was the connection in between the label and its outlet ;)